# Achieving a facebook-like modal dialog in GTK+ (linux)

Tags: python, gtk

Ideally, the transparent border.

Here's an example of what i'd like to achieve:
[image]

Notice the transparent border.

Now i suppose I could use cairo to create a rectangle with transparency, and put a borderless non-transparent window inside, mimic'ing that effect - which I would if i knew the window would have a fixed dimension. However, if the inner window grows, it'll grow out of the transparent rectangle.

How should one approach such task?

Comment: Hi, are you using GTK2 or GTK3 for this ? The themes engines have been rewritten for GTK3, to use CSS, and what you're trying to do may be easily done in CSS.

Comment: At the moment in gtk2, but ill look into gtk3. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making window frames is really the job of the window manager (at least under X11, don't know how it works on windows).

But have a look at the [GtkBin](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkBin.html), [GtkBox](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkBox.html) or [GtkMisc](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkMisc.html) widgets. Pack the dialog inside it as a single widget, and use padding to give it a size. Read up on [GTK+ drawing model](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/chap-drawing-model.html). You will probably need to set a flag and define your own `expose-event` handler to re-draw your frame.